# Why code is showing z output instead of 1?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module dulladd (C,A,B);

input A,B;
output C;
wire w1,w2;

not notl (w1,B);
or orl (w1,B);
or or2 (A,w2);

endmodule

/* 
 * Do not change Module name 
*/
module main;
  reg A,B;
  wire C;
 dulladd dulll (C,A,B);
  
  initial
  begin
     A=0;
     B=1;
     #5 // Wait 5 time units.
     $display ("carry = ",C);
  end 
endmodule
```

i need someone to please explain to me in simple terms why my output is z and not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your simulations shows:

> carry = z

because `C` in the `dulladd` module is not driven by any logic.

In module `dulladd`, you declared the `C` module port:

```
output C;
```

However, you did not connect it to anything else.  The default type of the port is `wire`, and the `wire` type defaults to the `z` value (high impedance).

You need to connect `C` to something inside the `dulladd` module.

---

Your code is strange in other ways, too.  For example, you use `or` gates, but you only connect 2 signals to them.  While this is legal syntax, an `or` gate would typically have 3 or more connections: one output and 2 or more inputs.

Another oddity is that you connect the module input (`A`) to the output port of the `or` gate.  From IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 28.4 *and, nand, nor, or, xor, and xnor gates*:

> These six logic gates shall have one output and one or more inputs.
> The first terminal in the terminal list shall connect to the output of
> the gate and all other terminals connect to its inputs.